# Show viewcontroller by storyboard id inside UITabBarController

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to show a specific viewcontroller, inside my UITabBarController by using the viewcontrollers storyboard id.

I can only get the viewcontroller to be shown without the UITabBarController.

How do I also show the UITabBarController?

I have tried this:

```
let identifier = "stats_view"
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: identifier)
        window?.rootViewController = vc
```

Which gave me the problem listed above.

Comment: A bit more information will be needed than that. Are you trying to populate your tab bar view controller dynamically by storyboard identifiers? Or are you trying to show one of the view controllers already inside the tab bar view controller which should be identified by storyboard identifier? And where do you want to make the change from?

Comment: @MaticOblak I want to show a viewcontroller (from app delegate) that is already in the UITabBarController. So instead of for instance showing the first tab "News" it goes directly to the second tab "Events".

Comment: @M.Holm -- is "stats_view" a `UIViewController` or your `UITabBarController`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the following code.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    if let myTabBar = self.window.rootViewController as? UITabBarController { // Getting Tab Bar
        myTabBar.selectedIndex = 2 //Selecting tab here
        return true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set `selectedIndex` of `tabBarController` to view specific `viewController` which are embedded in `tabBarController`. Use following code.

```
self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 1
```

Comment: I want the code to work in AppDelegate, and it says it has no member of tabBarController?